# 2 class of col-md-6 can't make element stack horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make footer that consist of 2 anchor text and I want to make both of those anchor text placed side by side (not vertically).

Here's my HTML:

```
<footer>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href='#'>BRAND</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href='#'>Social 1</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href='#'>Social 2</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href='#'>Social 3</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</footer>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 10%);
}
```

Here's my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32gund40/2/)
Can you help me figure it out what's wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Are you including bootstrap?

Comment: The html in the above snippet and the jsfiddle are different and you did not link the bootstrap css file to the jsfiddle.

Comment: This is how it looks with the bootstrap css added: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/216/

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea to add `col-md-2` to each link. Make sure you have the bootstrap CSS loaded on the page.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Make sure you're viewing the page on `md` (or larger) screen size. Alternatively, use `col-sm-*` or `col-xs-*` styles. Following sizes are used:

```
xs: Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px)
md: Small devices (tablets, 768px and up)
sm: Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up)
lg: Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
```

An improvement would be to use `col-md-offset-2 col-md-2` on the first link, instead of `col-md-6`.

```css
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125, 126, 125, 1) 0%, rgba(14, 14, 14, 1) 10%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Shows this working with `col-xs-*` (to make it viewable on small code snippet screen). -->
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-2">
        <a href='#'>BRAND</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a href='#'>Social 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a href='#'>Social 2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a href='#'>Social 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues with it after fixing the bootstrap link. Are you sure you have viewed the outcome in the browser window wide enough - so you are not rendering a smaller than medium (md) view?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/32gund40/6/

Updated fiddle you weren't including the bootstrap stylesheet

Adjust the `col-md-6` classes to `col-xs-6` if you need it the same col width on mobile

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<div class="clear:both"></div>
```

just before the closing tag of **row** div
and distribute the tags like I did.

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href='#'>BRAND</a>
            </div>
            *<div class="col-md-6">*
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href='#'>Social 1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href='#'>Social 2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href='#'>Social 3</a>
            </div>
            *</div>*
            **<div class="clear:both"></div>**
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```